# Can you connect ManifoldCF to Documentum without Webtop?

Tags: documentum, manifoldcf

I am working on a proof of concept connecting Documentum as a repository to ManifoldCF and Solr as an output.  The ManifoldCF widget to connect to Documentum is asking for a Webtop URL and it won't allow me to leave it blank.  We have not implemented Webtop at my company.  Can ManifestCF connect to Documentum without Webtop?

Comment: did you try to enter Documentum Administrator URL instead of Webtop? (I assume you are having it on your environment).

Comment: I just tried it and it didn't work.